# Как каждый раз создавать уникальную ссылку для результата?

Tags: python, django

В общем, делаю страницу на сайте. Смысл таков: человек заходит, загружает xml файл, выбирает несколько параметров и ему выдаётся результат. Я не нашёл, как обрабатывать xml файл сразу. Поэтому я загружаю его файл с параметрами в базу, а потом перенаправляю нас страницу с результатом. Всё отлично работает, но есть проблема. Я не придумал как каждый раз создавать уникальную ссылку для результата. Сейчас у меня одна ссылка для результатов и там просто показывается последний...
views.py загрузчика

```
def upload_file(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('lessons:index')
else:
    form = DocumentForm()
return render(request, 'templates/upload/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

views.py обработчика

```
def lessons_view(request):

        a = keker()

        return render(request, 'templates/lessons/ocenki.html', {'ocenki': a})
```

keker это сам обработчик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В модель с результатами добавить поле guid, по которому тот кто имет ссылку модет получить файл. ID не подойдут, так как из-за них можно легко перебрать все результаты и получить лишнее.

в urls.py нужно добавить

```
 url(r'(?<guid>.+)/$, lessons_view, name=<your_view_name>),
```

При переходе по этому URL нужно будет доставать guid и по нему искать. Если не найден - 404, естественно

А что касается обработки XML, хотелось бы узнать подробнее, но врятли кто ответит спустя 11 месяцев. Были интересны подробности, ибо вероятно можно было обработать сразу

Answer (score 0):

Сделать ресурс (view) который бы в GET принимал, например, ID и по этому ID брал из БД результаты и выдавал страницу.